invalid_scope when trying to request dm_channels.messages.write from Discord OAuth
I'm trying to update the scopes requested by my Discord OAuth flow, I'm trying to add dm_channels.messages.write, this is the URL the Discord developer portal generates for me (some info redacted):
https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize
  ?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
  &response_type=code
  &redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>
  &scope=identify+email+guilds.members.read+guilds.join+guilds+dm_channels.messages.write

For some reason, after I authenticate with this link, the redirect URL points to:
?error=invalid_scope
&error_description=The+requested+scope+is+invalid%2C+unknown%2C+or+malformed.

Can anyone help me understand why isn't this working? The flow works without the dm_channels.messages.write scope in the list.

some scopes require a discord approval. Seems that you have to contact discord support and ask for approval.

